# Encontrar el máximo y mínimo de una pila, sin depender de la cantidad de elementos

Tags: java, pilas

¿Cómo busco el máximo y mínimo dentro de una pila realizando un número constante de operaciones? Es decir, que no dependa del número de elementos de la pila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasta donde yo conozco, creo que lo que pides es imposible. El tiempo que se tarda en buscar un elemento en una colección está directamente relacionado con los elementos que hay en la misma. Hay muchos métodos para buscar elementos en una colección pero ninguno te va a dar un número constante de operaciones. Se puede optimizar dependiendo de diversos criterios, como de si los elementos están ordenados o no, etc... pero aún así, el número de iteraciones va a estar influido por el número de elementos.

Comment: Yo diría que depende de la implementación de la pila. Si es una pila común y corriente basada en una lista (usualmente una lista enlazada), esto es imposible. Si se usa un heap, específicamente un heap binario, es posible obtener o el máximo o el mínimo en tiempo constante, pero no ambos.

Answer (score -1):

Con Pilas no mi amigo, con arboles, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]si.

El nodo mas lejano hacia la derecha es el mayor.

Comment: detallá mejor tu respuesta, ¿por qué arboles en lugar de pilas?

Comment: Dos problemas: 1) no es tiempo constante, es log(n) donde N es la cantidad de elementos en el árbol. 2) el/la autor/a pide usar una pila, y le cambias la respuesta por completo. Lo mejor en estas situaciones es evitar responder o responder con un "no se puede" si eso es lo que consideras.